# Django - How to port scripts to django

Tags: python, django

Before I ask my question I need to give some context:

I wrote a simple python script that read linux's syslog file and search for certain strings. I have other similar scripts like these (scripts that do file system stuff, scripts that interact with other servers and so on). Most of these scripts write simple write stuff to stdout.

I would like to port these scripts to a web-server so I could simple browser to https://server/syslog and get the same output that I would get by running the script on the command line interface.

According with my research Django seems to be a great choice. I followed some Django tutorials and I was capable of developing some basic django web apps.

My question is: Since django does not have a "controller" where should I place the scripts code? My best bet in the view, but according with djangos documentation it does not make sence.

*Extracted from django doc: In our interpretation of MVC, the “view” describes the data that gets presented to the user. It’s not necessarily how the data looks, but which data is presented. The view describes which data you see, not how you see it. It’s a subtle distinction.*

Comment: No, you can make custom commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: If you don't need an ORM, authentication etc. then consider using Flask since it allows you to simply associate URLs to functions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I It may help me. But I'm not sure if I will be able to execute the script by browsing an URL.

Answer (score 1):

The description of MVC is not so important. The typical use of django is for database backed web applications. And this describes a design pattern or paradigm for that. It's completely possible to use django in other ways as well.

If you want to build a django app that is a web interface for your existing scripts, you might not even need the django ORM at all. In any case, you can put as much or as little logic in your view as you want. Your use case might just not fit neatly into the MVC or MVT paradigm. Django views are just python functions (or classes, but Django class based views are more tightly coupled with the ORM).

Comment: Thank you. What should I use? I liked django because of the admin interface. I was pretending to control access to these scripts through it.

Comment: The admin site is tightly bound to the ORM. For create/read/update/delete operations on the data in the database. That could possibly work well with your existing scripts, by storing output in the database. Can't give you any more specific advice. Stack Overflow is not really a site for open ended questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

1. leaving your scripts largely as they are, but wrap the parts you want to reuse as 
   functions. You can keep them functional as standalone scripts with an

   `if __name__=='__main__':`

   block to call the functions.
2. Import the functions to views.py - it doesn't matter where they are as long as your server will always be able to find them. I put mine right in the app directory.
3. Call the function(s) in your view(s), and return the text to a HttpResponse object which you return from the view. (I think this is more direct than creating a template and a context and calling render, but its not what I usually do so there may be some issues?)

Answer (score 0):

Thats bit old code - but you will get enough idea to start - check `https://github.com/alex2/django_logtail` **(Django_LogTail)**